# SQL-Server Get data of each day that falls between two dates

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table with job schedules :

```
job_id  [unique ID]
pref_start [date]
spec_duration [time in seconds]
```

I can calculate the end date from the preferred start and duration.  The pref_start is not fixed, and can be changed at whim by the engineers.

I need to report activity in any given week, so if I have data similar to:

```
jid   start        end 
J1    01/01/yyyy   15/02/yyyy
J2    07/01/yyyy   08/02/yyyy
J3    09/02/yyyy   21/03/yyyy
```

How would I query "tell me the job id's that occur on each day of the week 07/02/yyyy to 12/02/yyyy"

Comment: SQL has `between` as an operator https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: Before you use `BETWEEN` you'll want to read [Aaron Bertrand's blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) on this. You haven't given us enough information to help you though. [This example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/95107) should give you some information on what else we need. And those *dates* look like *strings* to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the matching intervals between your jobs and your filtering interval, then the amount of days for the filter interval and the overlapping intervals must match:

```
DECLARE @Jobs TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY, 
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE)

INSERT INTO  @Jobs (
    StartDate,
    EndDate)
VALUES
    ('2019-01-01', '2019-02-15'),
    ('2019-01-07', '2019-02-08'),
    ('2019-02-09', '2019-03-21')


DECLARE @FilterStartDate DATE = '2019-02-07'
DECLARE @FilterEndDate DATE = '2019-02-12'


;WITH AtLeast1DayOverlappingJobs AS
(
    SELECT
        J.ID,
        J.StartDate,
        J.EndDate,
        OverlappingStartDate = CASE
            WHEN J.StartDate > @FilterStartDate THEN J.StartDate ELSE @FilterStartDate END, -- Highest of 2
        OverlappingEndDate = CASE
            WHEN J.EndDate < @FilterEndDate THEN J.EndDate ELSE @FilterEndDate END -- Lowest of 2
    FROM
        @Jobs AS J
    WHERE
        -- They share at least 1 day
        @FilterStartDate <= J.EndDate AND @FilterEndDate >= J.StartDate
)
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    AtLeast1DayOverlappingJobs AS T
WHERE
    -- Amount of days must match between filter and overlapping periods
    DATEDIFF(DAY, @FilterStartDate, @FilterEndDate) = DATEDIFF(DAY, T.OverlappingStartDate, T.OverlappingEndDate)
```

Results:

```
ID  StartDate   EndDate     OverlappingStartDate    OverlappingEndDate
1   2019-01-01  2019-02-15  2019-02-07              2019-02-12
```

Comment: Thank you, very elegant.